# Java run time error when running the jar created from Maven (3.0.5) build using ess_es_server, ess_japi jar

Tags: java, maven

I have a strange issue; I'm trying to run the jar created from maven build thru command prompt, but it gives run time error. When I'm running this from eclipse, it runs fine. Also, build is successful. Here's what I'm doing:

1. Created a java swing project (java 1.7) and tested successfully in eclipse
2. pushed the code to git for others to review and to be merged to master
3. once I got the go ahead after some minor changes (comments only), cloned it to a dev folder and keep it separate
4. ran mvn archetype:generate and create a mvn project w/ pom.xml
5. import this project to eclipse and retrofit the clean code from dev folder
6. modified pom.xml for dependency on the 3rd party jars (ess_es_server, ess_japi) and saved in eclipse.
7. came back to cmd prompt;compiled, packaged to create the jar- it was successful
8. while launching the app (java -cp < cp with jar) pkg.app, it gives error
   “…java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/essbase/api/base/EssException” whenever it's trying to invoke that particular class pertaining to one of the 3rd party jars
9. I have installed these 3rd party jars to my .m2 repo since they are not available in public repository.

Can someone help? My suspicion is my GAV parameters are not correct.

Comment: It sounds to me like you do not have com/essbase/api/base/EssException on your classpath at runtime.  Please edit your question and indicate  exactly the command line you are using to run your program.  I do not understand what java -cp < cp with jar means.  Maven will not put all the classes your project depends on into your pom's artifact.  To do that you need to use something like the maven assembly plugin with the single goal.  You should also post your pom.xml.

Comment: Yes; found out the cause. While compiling it takes the jars from .m2 repo, during run time, it needs explicitly the jars. I have created a lib under the project folder and mentioned it while running. It runs fine. Below is the command I'm giving while running from cmd prompt:C:\Users\OND983\mvn\ej>java -cp C:\Users\OND983\mvn\ej\target\ej-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\OND983\mvn\ej\lib\* com.capitalone.essbaseja
va.view.LoginView

Comment: Who/what put those jars in the lib directory to begin with I wonder?  IntelliJ won't do it by default.

Answer (score 0):

While running explicitly mention the library from where java program should pick up the jars; .m2 repo is used for compilation time only.